# Groovy syntax highlighting for Kate

Tags: grails, groovy, syntax-highlighting, kate

Is there a way to add syntax highlighting for the **Groovy** language in `kate`?

Or is there a quite similar language, that will work as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can put [this xml file](https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=84306) under `/usr/share/apps/katepart/syntax/` if you want it to be installed at system's level, otherwise in 
 `~/.kde4/share/apps/katepart/syntax/` if you want it at user's level:

```
mkdir -p ~/.kde/share/apps/katepart/syntax
cd ~/.kde/share/apps/katepart/syntax
wget http://docs.codehaus.org/download/attachments/2747/groovy.xml
```

This works for KDE4. For other versions you might follow this [blog post](https://vortex7.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/editing-groovy-with-the-%CE%BAate-editor/).

Comment: http://codelearnings.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/syntax-highlighting-for-groovy-in-kate.html : To make Groovy syntax highlighting work, I instead had to place the groovy.xml file into

~/.kde/share/apps/katepart/syntax/

in order to make it available for a single user or in

/usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax

to make it available system wide. Restart Kate, here you go. It gets picked up automatically when you save a .groovy file and resides in the Tools -> Highlighting -> Sources menu.

Comment: It kind of works, when saving a file, but I cannot find it inside the "Tools -> Highlighting -> Sources menu"

Comment: Hey Rubo - ye I found its tricky if you open a groovy and it don't highlight it - do save after which it does... so requires 1 save action per time it does not highlight

Comment: @vahid: yes, so it seems the integration is not completely correct, but it helps already a lot (you can delete your first comment)

Comment: I added your comment to the answer, SDI you can remove all non-essential comments here

Comment: Since the link above is dead, try this one instead: https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=84306 (someone suggested KDE incorporated it into Kate, but the case seems stuck)